# aspnet web forms An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: asp.net, webforms, model-binding

I am using asp net 4.5.2 with model binding; I have a problem that whenever I try to use model binding on DropDownList It raises the error `An item with the same key has already been added` but if I change it to SQLDataSource the error goes away.
Thanks in advance

---

Update

Sample Code

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvChairItem" DataKeyNames="ChairItemId" InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" OnItemCanceling="lv_ItemCanceling" OnItemUpdated="lv_ItemUpdated" OnItemEditing="lv_ItemEditing" ClientIDMode="AutoID" OnCallingDataMethods="ChairItem_CallingDataMethods" SelectMethod="GetByChairId" InsertMethod="InsertItem" UpdateMethod="UpdateItem" DeleteMethod="DeleteItem" ItemType="App.Model.ChairItem">
.............
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        ........
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRoomId" CssClass="" DataValueField="Value" DataTextField="Text" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Text='<%# BindItem.RoomId %>' Width="100%" OnCallingDataMethods="Room_CallingDataMethods" SelectMethod="GetAllForDDL" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
                <asp:ListItem Value="">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        ........
    </tr>
</InsertItemTemplate>
.....................
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Post some code, need more info to help. Your model is generating the same value for the key/value for each ListItem.

Comment: Thanks But I fixed it by adding EnableViewState=False to All dropdownlists

Answer (score 0):

Then the issue is likely because you are populating it on page load without checking for Page.IsPostBack. You don't want to re-populate the controls on each postback. You do want to (often) allow ViewState. So I would re-enable, and wrap your populate method in (not page.ispostback).

Comment: I am using Model Binding on Control it is not related to PageLoad

Comment: Then your binding event is happening twice. That's why you get duplicate keys, except when you deactivate viewstate, though I would imagine that only occurs on postback? Because otherwise turning off viewstate wouldn't likely help unless I'm misunderstanding something...

Comment: Have you ever tried asp net webforms model binding with dropdownlists

Comment: Yes, I have been using webforms for twelve years, Object Data Sources frequently, and EF, Linq for the last 3 years, sporadically.